# Using Boost bisection when the function relies on a class attribute and has additional arguments

Tags: c++, boost, bisection

I am trying to use the Boost bisection method described [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/develop/libs/math/doc/html/math_toolkit/roots/roots_noderiv/bisect.html).

I have seen a couple of examples of how to get this to work, e.g. [How to use boost bisection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8245909/how-to-use-boost-bisection), but I don't understand how to apply these to my particular set-up.

Here is a sketch of some code that illustrates what I am trying to do.

```
class Model {
    double b;
    double root;
public:
    double func(double x, double c);
    void solve(void);
};


double Model::func(double x, double c) {
    return (x*x*x + (b*x) + c);
}

void Model::solve(void) {

    double c;

    b = 2.;
    c = 1.;

    // root = bisect(func(), from, to, ...);
    // where the first argument to func() is what we want to find the root over
    // and the second argument to func() is c

}

int main(void) {
    Model model;
    model.solve();
}
```

The member function `solve()` needs to find the root of the member function `func()`. `func()` has two important features:

1. It relies on the class attribute `b`
2. It has a second argument `c` that is determined in `solve()`. I want to hold this second argument fixed when finding the root

How would I implement the Boost bisection method in this context? [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8299107/using-boostbind-to-bind-member-function-to-boostbisect) answer seems to suggest that boost::bind might solve part of the problem but I don't understand enough of it to know how to apply it to my problem.

Comment: Do you have C++11? Then just use a lambda.

Comment: Also, if your function is differentiable, consider using Newton method. That's already quite a bit better for C1 functions and crazy good for C2.